# How can I stub a chain of calls to an AWS client object using AWS SDK V2 tests?

Tags: ruby, aws-sdk, stub, rspec3

I am upgrading our implementation of AWS to V2. I would like to create an AWS client object in my tests, whose web requests are stubbed. The problem I have is getting this test client to correspond to the real client, such that I can test methods that may be called on the client in the code.

My test suite is RSpec. To give you an illustration of the problem:

```
aws_client = Aws::DynamoDB::Client.new(stub_responses: true)
```

is its own object. If created in the test, it won't correspond to the client in the code as an instance_double would:

```
let(:client) { instance_double(Aws::DynamoDB::Client) }
before do
  allow(Aws::DynamoDB::Client).to receive(:new).and_return(client)
  allow(client).to receive(<some_method>).with(<some parameters>)...
end
```

You can see that "client" is being used to test whether the code is communicating with the API in the desired way. The test depends on whether the code uses the correct methods with the correct parameters.

How can I get an object like aws_client (as opposed to an instance double) to correspond to client so there are no unauthorized calls to the API, and so I can test the methods that are called on the client in the code?

When I tried to globally or partially stub the AWS config responses in the spec_helper or the test file (`Aws.config[:stub_responses] = true`), I still see unauthorized API requests.

Answer (score 0):

You may look at https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/working-with-legacy-code/message-chains
(receive_message_chain)

```
    allow(double).to receive_message_chain(:foo, :bar).and_return(:baz)
```

Comment: Relevant text should be copied into this answer in case the link goes dead in the future

Comment: Thank you.  I would prefer not to use message_chain except as a last resort (if possible, I would like to stub the method calls on the AWS object individually).  My question is about how to test the calling of <some_method> using the AWS-created tests, so this addresses a different issue.

Comment: I think that what my team would like to see is an AWS SDK solution.